# OpenIddict: OpenIddict-Client add a New Client Registration with multiple RedirectUris

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, openiddict

I had been playing around with the OpenIddict library for a small side project of mine, where I want to make use of the OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code flow + PKCE. In addition to this, I also went with following the "backend for frontend" design.

I was happy to learn the author of the library wrote a blog post pertaining to the new OpenIddict client. I went with registering my client on my backend-for-frontend app (which is a confidential client with both a secret and client id) https://kevinchalet.com/2022/02/25/introducing-the-openiddict-client/

My question is, if you have registered an OpenIddict client, which has multiple RedirectUri's, how do you add those redirectUri's, when you register your clients on the consuming app (i.e.: the backend for fronend)?

On my authorization server, I make use of a hosted service to create the OpenIddict client, which is persisted to my database. Below is a snippet of that code:

```
public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
        var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbContext>();
        var authClientsCache = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IAuthClientCache>();

        await dbContext.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await authClientsCache.Clear().ConfigureAwait(false);

        var appManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOpenIddictApplicationManager>();

        if (await appManager.FindByClientIdAsync(DevClientConstants.ClientId, cancellationToken)
                .ConfigureAwait(false) == null)
        {
            var devSettings = _appConfiguration.Create(SettingNames.DevSettings);
            var devBff = new OpenIddictApplicationDescriptor
            {
                ClientId = DevClientConstants.ClientId,
                ClientSecret = DevClientConstants.ClientSecret,
                ConsentType = OpenIddictConstants.ConsentTypes.Implicit,
                Type = OpenIddictConstants.ClientTypes.Confidential,
                RedirectUris =
                {
                    new Uri($"{devSettings.BaseUrl}/Account/LoginCallback"),
                    new Uri($"{devSettings.BaseUrl}/Account/LoginAdminCallback"),
                },
                DisplayName = "Dev BFF (Backend for Frontend)",
                Permissions =
                {
                    OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Endpoints.Authorization,
                    OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Endpoints.Token,
                    OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Endpoints.Logout,
                    OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Endpoints.Introspection,
                    OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                    OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.GrantTypes.RefreshToken,
                    OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.GrantTypes.AuthorizationCode,
                    OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.ResponseTypes.Code,
                    OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Scopes.Profile,
                    OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Scopes.Email,
                    OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Scopes.Roles
                },
            };

        }
    }
```

Then, on my backend (backend for frontend), I register my client:

```
public static void ConfigureOpenIddictClient(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection,
        IConfiguration configuration, bool isDevelopment)
    {
        var appConfig = configuration.GetSection(SettingNames.DevSetting).Get<DevSetting>();

        serviceCollection.AddOpenIddict()
            .AddCore(config => { config.UseEntityFrameworkCore().UseDbContext<DbContext>(); })
            .AddClient(config =>
            {
                config.AllowPasswordFlow();
                config.AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow();
                config.AllowRefreshTokenFlow();
                config.AllowClientCredentialsFlow();

                config.AddEncryptionCertificate(SecurityCertificateHelper.GetEncryptionCertificate())
                    .AddSigningCertificate(SecurityCertificateHelper.GetSigningCertificate())
                    .AddSigningKey(new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(EncryptionConstants
                            .TokenSigningKey)));


                config.UseAspNetCore().EnableStatusCodePagesIntegration().EnableRedirectionEndpointPassthrough()
                    .EnablePostLogoutRedirectionEndpointPassthrough();
                config.UseSystemNetHttp()
                    .SetProductInformation(typeof(Program).Assembly);

                config.AddRegistration(new OpenIddictClientRegistration
                {
                    ClientId = DevClientConstants.ClientId,
                    ClientSecret = DevClientConstants.ClientSecret,
                    RedirectUri = new Uri($"{appConfig!.BaseUrl}/Account/LoginCallback"),
                    ProviderName = "Local",
                    Issuer = new Uri(appConfig!.AuthorizationServerBaseUrl),
                    Scopes =
                    {
                        OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Email,
                        OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Profile,
                        OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Roles,
                        OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.OfflineAccess
                    }
                });
            });
    }
```

Upon inspecting the documentation provided for the `RedirectUri` property on the `OpenIddictClientRegistration` class, I see it makes mention of another class where redirect urls are appended to some list:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the URI of the redirection endpoint that will handle the callback.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Note: this value is automatically added to
/// <see cref="OpenIddictClientOptions.RedirectionEndpointUris"/>.
/// </remarks>
```

Is the above comment a clue to solving my issue? How does one register a client which has multiple RedirectUri's?

I am currently using OpenIddict v4.3.0.

Thanks!

Comment: There should exist configuration to add multiple RedirectUris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking & reasoning about things a little bit more, I went with creating a separate backend app to support each frontend app individually. (User App -> User App Backend, and Admin App -> Admin App Backend). In each backend app, I use the OpenIddict Client middleware to register the respective client app.

Each of these backend apps are registered as private, confidential clients on OpenIddict, in the Authorization server app.

Comment: It's indeed the right approach 

Comment: Thank you for the validation! I am happy knowing the approach I devised here is the right approach! Thanks for maintaining such a wonderful library! Will accept this as the answer!